# F#: Is there an infix operator that could allow to reuse an object methods over subsequent |>?

Tags: f#, infix-operator

A colleague of mine is converting the C# below to F#:

```cs
string GetLatestTestResultXmlPath() =>
    new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(projFolder, "TestResults"))
        .GetDirectories()
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTime)
        .First()
        .GetDirectories("Out")
        .First()
        .GetFiles("*.log")
        .First()
        .FullName
```

The most natural result he got was:

```ml
let latestTestResultFilePath =
    (new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(projFolder, "TestResults")))
        .GetDirectories()
        .OrderByDescending(fun d -> d.LastWriteTime)
        .First()
        .GetDirectories("Out")
        .First()
        .GetFiles("*.log")
        .First()
        .FullName
```

While it's completely fine, he was wondering whether he could get something that using an infix operator over subsequent pipe forward `|>` operators. Something along those lines:

```ml
let latestTestResultFilePath =
    let directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(projFolder, "TestResults"))
    directoryInfo 
    |> (// magic operator here).GetDirectories()
    |> (// magic operator here).OrderByDescending(fun d -> d.LastWriteTime)
    |> (// magic operator here).First()
    |> (// magic operator here).GetDirectories("Out")
    |> (// magic operator here).First()
    |> (// magic operator here).GetFiles("*.log")
    |> (// magic operator here).First()
    |> (// magic operator here).FullName
```

I also got curious, and I am suspecting it might possible with an infix operator capable of doing, but not sure which one can actually fit that role.

This is purely out of curiosity.

Comment: The "magic operator" in this case would just be a lambda, `fun a -> a.GetDirectories()`, etc. The way your coworker did it is, in this case, probably much shorter than any other. Unless you want reusability, which obviously you'd roll it into separate functions, and then probably compose them (`>>`) to make it more F#ish.

Comment: @LSM07 He could have lost the `new` keyword, which is a C#ism. In F#, it is mandatory only for object construction expressions that implement `System.IDisposable`.

Comment: There's a proposal for a `_.Foo` syntax for this that's been discussed at length: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/506

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because you are using LINQ which is static extension.